# MVC Internal resource error after deploying to godaddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed my MVC website to GoDaddy and when trying to load it I get the following:-

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I have tried the detailed config in the web config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have also ensured the .NET framework of my project is the same as the hosting version

I have ensured all the relevant dll's are set to copy local = true

I have even added the following Application_Error method to my global.asax but it didn't do anything

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        KeyValuePair<string, object> error = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ErrorMessage", ctx.Server.GetLastError().ToString());
        ctx.Response.Clear();
        RequestContext rc = ((MvcHandler)ctx.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
        string controllerName = rc.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
        IController controller = factory.CreateController(rc, controllerName);
        ControllerContext cc = new ControllerContext(rc, (ControllerBase)controller);

        ViewResult viewResult = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
        viewResult.ViewData.Add(error);
        viewResult.ExecuteResult(cc);
        ctx.Server.ClearError();
    }
```

Are there any logs I can access from my hosting account?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I put only this in my web config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I got a much better error message and it was a level of security that was giving me grief.  I ended up needing to add

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

in the system.web section of my web.config file